# Comparison of two tables in Lua?

Tags: lua, traversal, lua-table

I would like to supply a table that has a subset of the fields used in the output of `os.date("*t")`, and see if the fields that are specified matches what is given by an actual `os.date("*t")` call. Like this:

```
function datetimeTableTrue (dt)
    local nowTodayTable = os.date("*t");
    for i, v in ipairs(dt) do
        print("ping");
        if not (dt[i] == nowTodayTable[i] ) then
            return(false);
        end
    end
    print("pong");
    return(true);
end

print(tostring(datetimeTableTrue({day=0,hour=15})))
```

I would expect a *false* here on a monday, as 'day' is given but is not 1. But, I always get a 'true' and never a "ping" output. How come?

Obviously, I am new to Lua, so please excuse my stupidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use pairs instead of ipairs, ipairs will only iterate through integer keys

```
function datetimeTableTrue(dt)
    local nowTodayTable = os.date("*t")
    for k, v in pairs(dt) do
        if nowTodayTable[k] ~= v then
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end

print(datetimeTableTrue({day=0, hour=15}))
```

Semicolons are not needed in Lua